# how to handle OPTIONS of SELECT using DOJO

Tags: dojo

I want write DOJO statement equivalent to following javascript statement:

```
document.form_name.select_name.options[0]=new Option("Q3","Q4",false,false);
```

can u help me please!

Answer (score 2):

Dojo is a JavaScript library, so JavaScript is still valid when using Dojo. An alternative would be the use of the `dojo/dom-construct` module which allows you to create DOM nodes. An example:

```js
require(["dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/domReady!"], function(domConstruct) {
    domConstruct.create("option", {
        value: "Q4",
        innerHTML: "Q3",
        defaultSelected: false,
        selected: false
    }, "test");
});
```

In this example I create an option based on the settings you provided. The placement of the `<option>` is based upon the third parameter `"test"`. This means that this option will be placed as the last option of a `<select>` with an ID called `"test"`.

An example JSFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/A5aRn/). There is also a [reference guide](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/dom-construct.html) and the [API documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/dom-construct) which might help you.

---

## Pre Dojo 1.7

If you need to make this to work on pre-Dojo 1.7, you need to remove the `require()` statement since this is a new feature since Dojo 1.7 and is called the AMD loader.
All modules (at least, most of them) have an alternative in pre-Dojo 1.7. `dojo/dom-construct` would become `dojo.create`.

`dojo/domReady!` would become `dojo.addOnLoad` but this works slightly different than the module (actually `dojo/domReady!` is a plugin) introduced in Dojo 1.7. I recommend reading the old documentation for more information.

Comment: In order to meet the requirement from the question, you can replace the string "text" to `dojo.query("INPUT[name=select_name]")[0]`

Comment: I left it somewhat incomplete so the author can try some things too. But you should change `INPUT` by `OPTION` since this isn't an `<input>`. To be conform with the coding style of the example above, I would recommend using the AMD loader for `dojo/query` too.

Comment: Thanks shawnzhu for your response! One more thing I would like to ask..., can we do it by restricting ourselves in DOJO 1.3.x ?  Because domConstructor comes under DOJO 1.7 or above

Comment: @MohammadLayeeque it's possible but that means you need to get rid of the AMD syntax. the `require()` statement would disappear, `domCunstruct.create` would become `dojo.create` and you need to wrap it in a `dojo.addOnLoad()` statement to make sure it's executed only if the page is loaded.